# Wordpress grid/list view

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know what the best way to implement a list/grid togglable view in wordpress would be?
To be more clear: the default view shows the posts in a list, I would like to have the option to show them in a grid. 
I have so far created a loop which shows only the thumbnails, and included it in another template. 
But I don't know how I would link to that view. Would I best off using an archive view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest solutions is to create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) containing a grid view and add a link to this page in the list view. Very simple but just what you need.

I had the same issue with pagination. WordPress has built in function posts_nav_link that automatically prints links to previous and next pages if needed. The problem is that this function works only with $wp_query instance of WP_Query (this instance is used by default, for example to get page's content or the latest posts in home). So the solution for you:

```
<?php
$temp=$wp_query;
$wp_query=null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query('showposts=4');
 while(have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(160,160) );?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endwhile;
posts_nav_link();
$wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

I think that's quite obvious and there is no need of explanation :) should be working

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to follow what you wrote, but I'm a bit stumped. I've got a grid page, which calls a loop-grid. Should I be going into the admin and creating a page? If I do that it just shows the page entry and not the post loop.. help :s

Comment: Yes, you have to go to admin and add a new page. Look at the right sidebar and you should see 'Template' select box. So select your template name, which consists of grid view, instead of default. If it doesn't work paste your template page source, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dude. I kind of got it working for now with this:

```
<?php $latest = new WP_Query('showposts=4'); ?>
<?php while( $latest->have_posts() ) : $latest->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(160,160) );?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I think my mistake was trying to get it to use `get_template_part( 'loop', 'grid' );` It would show the page, but no posts. Even if used `get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );`

I'll need to figure out the pagination, but I'm putting it down for now to work on something else. 
Thanks for your help so far! @Gediminas

Comment: I edited my answer, added solution for your pagination problem (if you haven't solved by yourself yet).