# Change List view to Grid View Posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm totally new in wordpress, and i have one blog. I want to change list views posts to grid view posts what will i do? Please tell me as much clear I can understand. which page which coloum i'll change code. thanx

Comment: You should ask for this to be moved to the WordPress SE site, it would be appropriate there. Additionally it would be helpful to know whether you're referring to having a grid view on the front facing side of the installation or the administration side(because the solution will differ depending on where you want a grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried the solution, but [here is an older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389311/wordpress-grid-list-view) for what appears to be the same question.